# Extrememly High Estimated Number of Rows in Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

[image]

I have a stored procedure running 10 times slower in production than in staging. I took at look at the execution plan and the first thing I noticed was the cost on Table Insert (into a table variable @temp) was 100% in production and 2% in staging.

The estimated number of rows in production showed almost 200 million row! But in staging was only about 33.

Although the production DB is running on SQL Server 2008 R2 while staging is SQL Server 2012 but I don't think this difference could cause such a problem.

What could be the cause of such a huge difference?

**UPDATED**

Added the execution plan. As you can see, the large number of estimated rows shows up in Nested Loops (Inner Join) but all it does is a clustered index seek to another table.

**UPDATED2**

Link for the plan XML included
[plan.xml](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D0A0244F4492D43!171&authkey=!AFrU-MbBA-iFgkY&ithint=file%2Cxml)

And SQL Sentry Plan Explorer view (with estimated counts shown)

[image]

Comment: The query optimizer didn't change from 2008 to 2012. Is the data the same in staging and production? Have you tried updating your statistics or running the SP with the recompile option?

Comment: The data is almost the same between the two. Staging has a little less but not much at all. Thanks.

Comment: I'll second @MartinSmith 's comment and add that they should be actual plans (not estimated). You can also use the SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to anonymize the table names if you're worried about that.

Comment: The staging execution plan would be nice to see as well. BTW 2012 did add enhancements on dealing with table variables and explain plans. Your DBA or may not have turned these recompile/resample options on.

Comment: And you should not be running things  in 2012 in dev/qa/stg  that you plan to put to a 2008 prod database.  Espcially the staging environment should be exactly like prod, same db backend, same operating system.

Comment: By the way, there's a [dba.se] site which could be more suitable for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me.

There are an estimated `90,991.1` rows going into the nested loops.

The table cardinality of the table being seeked on is `24,826`.

[If there are no statistics for a column and the equality operator is used, that means the SQL can’t know the density of the column, so it uses a 10 percent fixed value.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/)

`90,991.1 * 24,826 * 10% = 225,894,504.86` which is pretty close to your estimated rows of `225,894,000`

But the execution plan shows that only `1` row is estimated per seek. Not the `24,826` from above.

So these figures don't add up. I would assume that it starts off from an original 10% ball park estimate and then later adjusts it to 1 because of the presence of a unique constraint without making a compensating adjustment to the other branches.

I see that the seek is calling a scalar UDF `[dbo].[TryConvertGuid]` I was able to reproduce similar behavior on SQL Server 2005 where seeking on a unique index on the inside of a nested loops with the predicate being a UDF produced a result where the number of rows estimated out of the join was much larger than would be expected by multiplying estimated seeked rows * estimated number of executions.

But, in your case, the operators to the left of the problematic part of the plan are pretty simple and not sensitive to the number of rows (neither the rowcount top operator or the insert operator will change) so I don't think this quirk is responsible for the performance issues you noticed.

Regarding the point in the comments to another answer that switching to a temp table helped the performance of the insert this may be because it allows the read part of the plan to operate in parallel (inserting to a table variable would block this)

Comment: Thanks Marin for the analysis. I accept this answer because it seems the best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Run `EXEC sp_updatestats;` on the production database. This updates statistics on all tables. It might produce more sane execution plans if your statistics are screwed up.

Comment: TT. Thanks for the tip. I've run that and the result was the same.

Comment: @notlkk Ok, apparantly there's something else going on. Without seeing the actual Stored Procedure and an estimate of the number of rows in referenced tables it's hard to come up with a solid answer to your question. What I can say is that using table variables might be suboptimal if you have a lot of rows in it. There are no statistics for table variables, and using them in queries might produce bogus execution plans. Use a (local) temporary table instead.

Comment: TT. Switching from a table variable to temp table did help (about 4 times faster, but it's still 6 times slower than staging and staging is using a table variable). The query plan still shows the same large amount of estimated number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't run EXEC sp_updatestats; On a large system it could take hours, or days, to complete.  What you may want to do is look at the query plan that is being used on production. Try to see if it has a index that could be used and is not being used. Try rebuilding the index (as a side effect it rebuilds statistics on the index.) After rebuilding look at the query plan and note if it is using the index. Perhaps you many need to add an index to the table. Does the table have a clustered index?

As a general rule, since 2005, SQL server manages statistics on its own rather well. The only time you need to explicitly update statistics is if you know that if SQL Server uses an index the query would execute would execute a lot faster but its not. You may want to run (on a nightly or weekly basis) scripts that automatically test every table and every index to see if the index needs to be reorged or rebuilt (depending on how fragmented it is). These kind of scripts (on a large active OLTP system)r may take a long time to run and you should consider carefully when you have a window to run it. There are quite a few versions of this script floating around but I have used this one often:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, every table has a clustered index (the PK). I tried rebuilding all the indices but still to no avail. I don't see any table scans in the plan. Everything is either index seek or scan.

Comment: Are you using table variables in your proc? I have had a lot of success converting table variables to temp tables (with the # sign).

Comment: Benjamin, Switching from a table variable to temp table did help (about 4 times faster, but it's still 6 times slower than staging and staging is using a table variable) and the number of estimated rows is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is probably too late to help you.

Table Variables are impossible for SQL Server to predict. They always estimate one row and exactly one row coming back.

To get accurate estimates so that the better plan can be created you need to switch your table variable to a temp table or a cte.